# ArcGIS API: Stop rotating Home button

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Refer to this sample here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=styling-simple-theme

I added a Home button:

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/widgets/Search",
  "esri/widgets/Home",
], function(Map, MapView, Search, Home) {
```

and

```
  var homeBtn = new Home({
    view: view
  }, "homediv");
  homeBtn.startup();

  // Add the home widget to the top left corner of the view
  view.ui.add(homeBtn, "top-left");
```

Whenever I press the Home button, I will see a spinning circle.

Is there a way to stop that Home icon to turn into a spinning circle but to remain as a Home icon?

Refer [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/styling/) I am able to style the Home button but unable to figure out how to stop the spinning circle of the Home button.

Comment: Does it spin only for a short time when you click on it? If yes, that's the normal behavior. If it doesn't stop spinning, it means something is wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks @BelowtheRadar. It does spin and I do not want the spin when I click on it, i.e. I want to override the normal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out later, posting it here. Hopefully, it will help someone:

```
  .sassy-theme .esri-icon-home {
      animation: none;  
  }

  .sassy-theme .esri-icon-home::before {
     content: "\e62f";
   }
```